# Whitelabel Error Page en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Buen dia a todos, estoy teniendo un problema con springboot que es el Whitelabel error, esto sucede a pesar de que es existente el template.
Aqui lo que se intenta es que en la tabla de To Do's (Metodo listAllTodos) se agregue uno nuevo lo que envia a un formulario (add-todo) para agregar una nueva tarea, al momento de enviar dicho formulario aparece este error, ya que lo que se intenta es redirigir nuevamente a la tabla de un inicio trayendo la descripcion proporcionada con un metodo POST pero me lanza este error.

Aqui proporciono mi codigo;

```
package com.pao.springboot.myFirstWebApp.toDo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class toDoController {

   private toDoService todoSer;

public toDoController(toDoService todoSer) {
    super();
    this.todoSer = todoSer;
}

@RequestMapping("list-todos")
public String listAllTodos(ModelMap model){
    List<toDo> todos=todoSer.findByUser("Pao");
    model.addAttribute("todos", todos);
    return "listTodos";
}

@RequestMapping(value="add-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String newTodoPage(ModelMap model){
    return "newTodo";
}


@RequestMapping(value="add-todo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewTodo(@RequestParam String desc, ModelMap model) {
    //toDoService.addTodo((String)model.get("name"), desc,
      //      LocalDate.now().plusYears(1), false);
    return "redirect:list-todos";
    }
}
```

Comment: hola, yo no entiendo cual es el mensaje de error que te da exactamente

Comment: Hola, cuando mandaba a llamar al metodo newTodoPage con el metodo Get mandaba a un template html que era un formulario para agregar un nuevo To Do, pero al momento de darle submitt debia ir al metodo addNewTodo que tiene el metodo post y regresar a la lista de To Do's en vez de hacer eso mandaba un error, esto era porque en el formulario html en vez de method="post" lo tenia como action="post", un error muy simple, pero significativo

Comment: y sigo sin entender cual era el mensaje de error que te daba

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude resolverlo, el problema estaba que en el template HTML en el formulario en vez de tenerlo como

```
form method="post"
```

lo tenia como

```
form action="post"
```

Gracias por tomar el tiempo de leerme